# Como hacer un loop en batch para iterar los numeros

Tags: batch

Necesito hacer un archivo batch que itere los numeros por ejemplo del 1 al 25, por tanto el script que estaba intentando era tal que asi.

```
loop x
firefox.exe -CreateProfile userx
```

Por tanto quería iterar el caracter x, del 1 al 25 , para crear 25 usuarios pero no estoy seguro como hacerlo ya que soy un poco novato en programacion. Como podría iterar los numeros usando batch?

Answer (score 0):

para iterar se usa `for /L %n in (inicio,incremento,fin) do comando %n`

ejemplo:

```
for /L %n in (1,1,25) do @echo user%n
```

en tu caso sería algo así:

```
for /L %n in (1,1,25) do @firefox.exe -CreateProfile user%n
```